# Median filter in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to code a median filter for a 2D image in JAVA(eclipse).
Can you please tell me how to take an image as input before applying filtering?
I am a beginner.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pixel matrix can be prepared as,

you can have a matrix(2-D array) of x rows and y columns,

the position `array[x][y]` will contain pixel value for that particular point in image.

here x will be horizontal resolution and y will be vertical resoultion
e.g.- if pixel (50,200) has intensity of 200 then in matrix form it will be represented as `array[50][200]=200;`

after preparing this whole matrix ,you can apply the Median filtering algorithm on this 2-D array.

hope this helps!

good luck!

Comment: Thank you.That will surely help.Can i take the input image from the command line itself?and how do i see the image output?

Comment: actually image rendering part ,I do not have much idea and whenever you are doing this in java, you cannot give image as input, you will have to give individual pixel value to prepare the 2-D array, doing this in command-line will be hectic

Comment: okay.But supposing I already have an image and i have to apply a filter on it, how can i get to know the pixel values of the image?since i cant give the image as an input i need to know the pixel values right?

Comment: java might not be the ideal platform for this, you might want 'Image processing softwares'